# How to Get data From url value parameter $_GET in PHP

Tags: php

sorry i a begginer of php. I have url example here: http://example.com?category=software-hardware .Actual of category is **Software & Hardware** I using this script to get url above

```
foreach ( $key as $value ) {
    $c = array(' ', '&-');
    $d = array('-', '');
    echo "<a href=\"category/".strtolower(str_replace($c, $d, $value->kategori_laporan))."\" class=\"list-group-item\">".$value->kategori_laporan."</a>";   
}
```

How To get data from my condition url.? Sorry, i bad using english. I want to create url like category from slideshare. Please help me.! Thanks.!

Comment: From what I understand, you want to change software-hardward to Software & Hardware. Is that right?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for `$category =  $_GET["category"]` . Also check out this link to see if it helps clear things up http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem. Tell us what exactly you want?

Comment: `$value->kategori_laporan` <- that part is strange too! Why is `$value` an Object with the property `kategori_laporan` ? Reedit / Repost your question :)

Comment: exactly i want to create like url category from slideshare.net. my url http://example.com/category/software-hardware. Data of this category not show, because category in my database is Software & Hardware. :D

Comment: So you need change only "&" to "-" or some other cases there for example "soft hard" to "soft-hard" etc..

Comment: Yes, i already changed soft hard to soft-hard, but when i want to show post using that string. Data not found, because in my database i have category Soft & Hard. I also already changed soft-hard to soft hard using my script above. But the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

you can fetch it like:

```
$cat = $_GET['category'];
```

and you don't need any `foreach`

Comment: I use foreach to show all data category from my database.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is an associative array having all the query string keys values.

You can get value of any query string parameter from this array by passing the key of query string  parameter.

To get category you can use `$_GET["category"]` in your case.